# How to get the number of weeks from a date in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find the number of weeks passed from a particular month, till date.

Like if its Nov, 2013 (as of today, 10th Jan, 2014) it should return 9 weeks.

Is there a way to find it?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1466131.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  function differenceInWeeks(d1, d2) {
    var t2 = d2.getTime();
    var t1 = d1.getTime();

    return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7));
  }
```

The `getTime` function returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01, the rest is just maths.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function weeksSince(dateString){
 var date = new Date(dateString);
 var today = new Date();
 return Math.floor((today-date)/(1000*60*60*24*7));
}

console.log(weeksSince("January 01, 2014"));
console.log(weeksSince("January 01, 2013"));
console.log(weeksSince("January 01, 2012"));

=> 1
=> 53
=> 105
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
function weeks_between(date1, date2) {
// The number of milliseconds in one week
var ONE_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
// Convert both dates to milliseconds
var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
var date2_ms = date2.getTime();
// Calculate the difference in milliseconds
var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms);
// Convert back to weeks and return hole weeks
return Math.floor(difference_ms / ONE_WEEK);
}
```

If you want them to be very precise(including days and time) then use these jquery libraries for that:

**[timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)**

**[javascript pretty date](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/)**

Answer (score 1):

That's a little vague, and the other answers are correct - it's basically just maths once you understand how to get milliseconds out of a date...

Try this fiddle as a start;

http://jsfiddle.net/melchizidech/UGWe6/

```
Date.prototype.daysSince = function(newDate){
    var difference = this.valueOf() - newDate.valueOf();
    var msInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var days = Math.floor(difference / msInDay);
    return days;
};
```